# Concatenate variable value into non-string line of code

Tags: python, parameters

I have the following function:

```
def source_sheets(sheet_name)
    gc.open(sheet_name).sheet1.get_all_records()
```

How can I parameterise 'sheet1', so any number can replace 1? The fact that its not a string or not within brackets is really stumping me.

Comment: May be `getattr(gc.open(sheet_name), 'sheetn').get_all_records()`?

Comment: How would 'sheetn' be used in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `getattr`.

```
def source_sheets(sheet_name, sheet_num)
    sheet = getattr(gc.open(sheet_name), 'sheet{}'.format(sheet_num))
    records = sheet.get_all_records()
    # do something with records, for example return it
```

or possibly

```
def source_sheets(sheet_name, subsheet)
    sheet = getattr(gc.open(sheet_name), subsheet)
    records = sheet.get_all_records()
    # do something with records, for example return it
```

if the sub-sheets can have names other than `'sheet1'`, `'sheet2'`, ... and so on.

Comment: The top example works really well, thanks! Cody's pointed out a really obvious solution but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @LaurieBamber cody's solution is the correct answer for the library you are using. I'm not familiar with that library, so my answer just shows how to get an attribute by name in general.

Answer (score 1):

Is this `gspread`? Can't you use `get_worksheet` as shown [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet)?

```
gc.open(sheet_name).get_worksheet(0).get_all_records()
```